# Oracle join for 2 tables with detail row should return 1 if more than 1

Tags: oracle, join

Oracle sql query to return rows based on transaction type. This is used for analytical purpose

```
SELECT YEAR
       , MONTH
       , source
       , count(distinct T.tx_id  ) no_of_txn
       , sum((CASE WHEN D.type = 1 THEN 1  ELSE 0 END ))  A_TXN 
       , sum((CASE WHEN D.type = 2 THEN 1  ELSE 0 END )) d_TXN
FROM TXN_HEADER T , TXN_DETAIL D  WHERE OPEN_AMT > 0   
AND  T.tx_id  = D.tx_id (+)
AND  T.tx_id  in ( 23414, 23123)
GROUP BY YEAR,MONTH,source
```

output

```
YEAR   MONTH  SOURCE  NO_OF_TXN  A_TXN D_TXN
2012   09     11      2          17    2
```

here the total no of rows in the detail table is 19 (17 +2) and header 2 ( 2 Txn)

The required output for me is total txn 2,  a_txn 2 and D_txn 2. That means if a txn having more than 1 a_txn it willbe considered as 1 same for D_txn

Final expected output is

```
YEAR   MONTH  SOURCE  NO_OF_TXN A_TXN   D_TXN
2012   09     11      2         2       2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`COUNT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions039.htm#i82697) and `DISTINCT` with an *expression*: it will count all distinct and not null instance of *expression*. So this should do it if I understand your requirements correctly:

```
SELECT YEAR
       , MONTH
       , source
       , count(distinct T.tx_id  ) no_of_txn
       , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN D.type = 1 THEN T.tx_id END)  A_TXN 
       , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN D.type = 2 THEN T.tx_id END)  d_TXN
FROM TXN_HEADER T , TXN_DETAIL D  WHERE OPEN_AMT > 0   
AND  T.tx_id  = D.tx_id (+)
AND  T.tx_id  in ( 23414, 23123)
GROUP BY YEAR,MONTH,source
```